# Facebook stream: friend clicks on a link in my stream, app should read the friend ID and parent user ID

Tags: javascript, facebook

I wanna create a challenging game.
For that I need the User ID of the root/source User AND the challenger (friend)

SCENARIO:

- An App exists in a FB Page. The App(or fb-page) posts something in
  the stream of a user. (Example: "Challenge this user")
- If a friend of the user clicks the link (start a challenge with this user)
- I should be able to get the clicked user ID and the Challengers User ID

I am working with the JS-SDK

```
USER   <- Fetching this ID
  |
  '---> Friend  <- When this User clicks on the str
```

Is this possible? And when yes: How?

Comment: _“The App(or fb-page) posts something in the stream of a user. (Example: "Challenge this user")”_ – that would be a violation of [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) already – you are not allowed to post stuff on the user’s timeline that the user did not actively create them self (normally by typing it in). If your app is a real “Game” (category-wise), then look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/distribution/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas-games/feed/ for ways to promote your app.

Comment: I know that the user has to approve a post on his stream. My question was simplyfied. **The question is, is it possible to fetch the userID which has posted the challenge and make him related to the challenger**

Comment: Well simply add a user identifier to the link that you are posting. (Should probably not be the real FB user id, but either an internal id you use in your system, or the `third_party_id` that Facebook provides.)

Comment: Ah, ok, via Url params. That sounds clear now! Many thanks. Would you answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a user identifier to the link that you are posting. (Should probably not be the real FB user id, but either an internal id you use in your system, or the `third_party_id` that Facebook provides.)